How to mix audio with specific delays in FFMPEG
I have an array that contains paths to audio files along with delay durations (in ms). Something like ["audio1.wav", 300, "audio2.wav", 350, "audio3.wav", 280, "audio4.wav"]
I want to mix the audio such that every subsequent audio file is added after X delay, where X is the immediately proceeding delay duration.
Here's an illustration of what the final audio should look like:

Here's the code I've written (using the FFMpeg Kit library):
export const concatenateAudio = async (
  audioSequence: (string | number)[],
  outputFile: string
): Promise<string> => {
  try {
    let filterComplex = "";
    let inputs = "";
    let mixInputs = "";
    let currentOffset = 0;
    let inputIndex = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < audioSequence.length; i++) {
      const item = audioSequence[i];
      if (typeof item === "string") {
        // It's an audio file
        inputs += `-i "${item}" `;
        if (inputIndex === 0) {
          filterComplex += `[${inputIndex}:a]`;
          mixInputs += `[${inputIndex}:a]`;
        } else {
          filterComplex += `[${inputIndex}:a]adelay=${currentOffset}|${currentOffset}[delayed${inputIndex}];`;
          mixInputs += `[delayed${inputIndex}]`;
        }
        inputIndex++;
      } else if (typeof item === "number" && i < audioSequence.length - 1) {
        // It's a silence duration, add it to the current offset
        currentOffset += item;
      }
    }

    filterComplex += `${mixInputs}amix=inputs=${inputIndex}:dropout_transition=0[out]`;

    const command = `${inputs} -filter_complex "${filterComplex}" -map "[out]" -y "${outputFile}"`;
    console.log(`Executing FFmpeg command: ${command}`);

    const session = await FFmpegKit.execute(command);
    const returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
    const output = await session.getOutput();

    console.log(`FFmpeg output: ${output}`);

    if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
      return outputFile;
    } else {
      throw new Error(
        `FFmpeg process exited with returnCode ${returnCode}. Output: ${output}`
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error concatenating audio files: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
};

I don't think I'm using adelay properly. If anyone has any suggestions or advice, that would be super appreciated!
Update:
Command log:
Executing FFmpeg command: -i "file:///path/to/file1.wav" -i "file:///path/to/file2.wav" -i "file:///path/to/file3.wav" -i "file:///path/to/file4.wav" -i "file:///path/to/file5.wav" -i "file:///path/to/file6.wav" -i "file:///path/to/file7.wav" -i "file:///path/to/file8.wav" -i "file:///path/to/file9.wav" -i "file:///path/to/file10.wav" -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]adelay=533|533[delayed1];[2:a]adelay=512|512[delayed2];[3:a]adelay=513|513[delayed3];[4:a]adelay=505|505[delayed4];[5:a]adelay=503|503[delayed5];[6:a]adelay=517|517[delayed6];[7:a]adelay=536|536[delayed7];[8:a]adelay=514|514[delayed8];[9:a]adelay=505|505[delayed9];[0:a][delayed1][delayed2][delayed3][delayed4][delayed5][delayed6][delayed7][delayed8][delayed9]amix=inputs=10:dropout_transition=0[out]" -map "[out]" -y "file:///path/to/output.wav"

Getting this error:
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x600002662820] More input link labels specified for filter 'adelay' than it has inputs: 2 > 1
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x600002662820] Error linking filters
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument


Please provide the output of the  ${command} and ${output} console logs.
